# Turning list with 300 rows of nulls into dataframe in R?

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I'm working on a project with 3 dataframes in R, that I wish to turn into a single dataframe for analysis purposes.  There are two tables with 713 rows, and one with 413 rows (as far as I can tell, it's missing several days).  For the one with 413 rows, the days seem to be missing without a clear pattern.  Thus, unless I wanted to reduce my data to potentially less than a week of data, it'd be faster to knit together the dataframes as-is and see how it plays out further down.

I hoped to use the following code to first combine them into a list, then reduce the resulting list by its Id and Day columns (I've already cleaned ID to the point that there are no extra/missing ones across the three dataframes) before converting it to a dataframe ready to use.

```r
final_chart = list(new_activity, new_calories, new_sleep)
final_chart %>% reduce(full_join, by=c('Id','Day'))
final_chart = as.data.frame(do.call(cbind, final_chart))
```

The list and reduction commands run fine, as far as I can tell, with NAs in the right spots.  However, when the third runs, it returns with the error `Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE): arguments imply differing number of rows: 713, 413`.  Is there any way to give an NA, Null, or some sort of placeholder (I'm still somewhat new to R) to the rows where the right combination of ID and Day is not present in the chart?  As I'm missing 300 theoretical rows of data, I don't think I have the time or energy to plug in placeholder values by hand.

**EDIT:**  Wow, I'm tired.  I *just* realized that I didn't save the results of line 2.  No wonder it didn't work.  Sorry to bother y'all.

Comment: You’re not assigning the result of your full join. Did you mean `final_chart <- final_chart %>% reduce(full_join, by=c('Id','Day'))`? If so, that should give you what you want without any need for the following line.

Comment: If I’m misunderstanding something, please provide a sample of your three tables, e.g. using `dput(head(new_activity, 25))`, etc.

Comment: @zephryl I realized that *after* I posted this question.  Again, so sorry for that.  Feeling kinda silly after that -- I spent over an *hour* stuck on this...

Comment: please don’t worry about it! Been there myself many times.